# Ms Teams - Adaptive Cards Actions and Continue Conversations based on user Input

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-teams

I want to send a user a adaptive card with some options through a MS Teams Bot.
After I know what option the user picked, I want to have a specific reply.

My issues so far are:

- I don't know what option the user picked.
- I don't know how to reply the specific, text or maybe another adaptive card, based on the
  user's choice.

This is what I've tried so far.

**Adaptive card json**

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "ColumnSet",
      "columns": [
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "width": "stretch",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "ActionSet",
              "actions": [
                {
                  "id": "action 1",
                  "type": "Action.Submit",
                  "title": "Action.Submit"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "ColumnSet",
      "columns": [
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "width": "stretch",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "ActionSet",
              "actions": [
                {
                  "id": "action 2",
                  "type": "Action.Submit",
                  "title": "Submit action 2"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "ColumnSet",
      "columns": [
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "width": "stretch",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "ActionSet",
              "actions": [
                {
                  "id": "action 3",
                  "type": "Action.Submit",
                  "title": "Submit action3"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
}
```

**Message send**

```
    public async Task<string> SendAdaptiveCardToAccountEmailAsync(AdaptiveCardRequest adaptiveCard)
    {
        var teamsConversations = await GetTeamsConversationsByEmail(adaptiveCard.AccountEmail);

        var cardJson = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(".", "Resources", $"{adaptiveCard.Type}.json"));
        var card = AdaptiveCard.FromJson(cardJson).Card;
        
        var columnOne = (card.Body[0] as AdaptiveColumnSet).Columns[0].Items[0] as AdaptiveActionSet;
        columnOne.Actions[0].Title = adaptiveCard.Options[0];
        columnOne.Actions[0].Id = "Option 1";

        var columnTwo = (card.Body[1] as AdaptiveColumnSet).Columns[0].Items[0] as AdaptiveActionSet;
        columnTwo.Actions[0].Title = adaptiveCard.Options[1];
        columnTwo.Actions[0].Id = "Option 2";

        var columnThree = (card.Body[2] as AdaptiveColumnSet).Columns[0].Items[0] as AdaptiveActionSet;
        columnThree.Actions[0].Title = adaptiveCard.Options[2];
        columnThree.Actions[0].Id = "Option 3";

        var attachment = new Attachment()
        {
            Content = card,
            ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive"
        };


        var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(teamsConversations.ServiceUrl),
            _microsoftAppId,
            _microsoftAppPassword);

        AppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(teamsConversations.ServiceUrl);

        var activity = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();

        activity.From = new ChannelAccount(_teamsBotId, _teamsBotName);
        activity.Recipient =
            new ChannelAccount(
                teamsConversations.AccountId,
                teamsConversations.AccountName);
        activity.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(false,
            "personal",
            teamsConversations.ConversationId)
        {
            Id =
                teamsConversations.ConversationId
        };

        activity.Attachments.Add(attachment);


       connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(activity as Activity).Wait();

        return "ok";
    }
```

**User choice**

```
    protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        turnContext.Activity.RemoveRecipientMention();
        var text = turnContext.Activity.Text.Trim().ToLower();

        var replyText = $"You choose: {text}";

        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(replyText, replyText), cancellationToken);

    }
```

Using `watch` in visual studio I've tried to find `action 1` or `Option 1`, etc in `turnContext.Activity`, but with no success.

Any examples, advice, solutions?

Thanks

Comment: all types of examples you can find it here, https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore

Comment: @coder_b thanks, but not really covering my issues : https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/07.using-adaptive-cards/Bots/AdaptiveCardsBot.cs

Comment: I am entirety sure how you are testing actions, ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: @coder_b, thanks, will try with the emulator aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast your Adaptive Card Actions as `AdaptiveSubmitAction`, which has a `Data` property. That property is just of type Object, so you can attach anything you like to it, like a custom class (e.g. `MyActionObject`, with a property like `ActionType` or whatever. Here's an example:

```
public class MyActionObject {
   public string ActionType {get; set; }
}
```

then set your AdaptiveAction's Data to match that, something like:
`((AdaptiveSubmitAction)columnThree.Actions).Data = new MyActionObject() { ActionType = 'Action3' };

Later, when your bot receives the Activity from the user, you can look for this value, something like:

```
dynamic value = turnContext.Activity.Value as dynamic;
var data = value?.data?.data;
if (data?.ActionType == "Action3") // do something
```

Comment: Hello, I've tried this and it works, thanks. But, when I send my adaptive card can I get a correlation Id , in order to know that `Action3`, is correlated to the adaptive card that I've just send? Or how do I correlate `Action3` to the message I've just send? Let's say that I send a message with the adaptive card, can I get a `Id` to save it in my db, and also receive the Id in my turn Context, and also set the action in db?

Comment: glad it's working. In terms of correlation id, you can add anything you want to your MyActionObject. Right now it only has an ActionType but you could also add a CorrelationId string property, for instance, that will also get returned.

Comment: OFC. :) doh. Thanks